# Share folder from Host to Guest VM using KVM

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, file-sharing, kvm

I want to share a folder from the host (linux) to a Linux VM that is running on it.

After some research I used 9p (version = 9p2000.L) sharing, following instructions given on the link below:

http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/9p_virtio

PROBLEM: I am unable to read/write to the mounted folder.

mount command shows the mounted fs as : 9p (rw,trans=virtio,version=9p2000.L)

Even doing a simple "ls" command after entering the mount point says : Permission Denied.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the 9p kernel module is broken in some kernels (3.5, 3.11). I ungraded by guest to 3.10.9 and things started working! :)

I just went with a hunch and have no bug reports or anything to share. Now when I googled it,I see there are few other facing the similar problem and have solved it in a similar fashion.
 https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/36992

-HTH

Comment: Any chance you could elaborate on this as I'm having exactly the same problem. Do you have a reference to a but report or anything? Thanks